# db_query with where clause not returning anything

Tags: database

I ran following query on DB through PHPmyAdmin

```
SELECT * FROM field_data_field_country_feed WHERE entity_id=40848
```

And it worked and returned me the single row
But when I try to implement that in my custom services it is not returning anything.

```
$result1 = db_query("SELECT * FROM field_data_field_country_feed WHERE entity_id=40848")->fetchAll();
        var_dump($result1);
```

Please help

Comment: What type of entity is it?

Comment: entity_id is int(10)

Comment: I mean, is it a node?  profile2?  taxonomy?  user?  Or, is it a custom entity?

Comment: it is taxonomy term

Comment: And you simply want to get all the data from that field for that particular entity?

Comment: why don't you use `db_select()` ?

Comment: @vintorg yes.. thats what I want to do.

Comment: @Drupalist: no reason as such for not using db_select(). I though using db_query would be straight forward.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
$taxonomy_term = taxonomy_term_load(40848); // the 40848 is the term id
$field_items = field_get_items('taxonomy', $taxonomy_term, 'field_data_field_country_feed');
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. I tried that, but it still doesn't work

Comment: Can you dump the items in $field_items and post?

Comment: yes, already did that. It returns bool(false)

Comment: Try this, dump the vals from $taxonomy_term, and post:

    $taxonomy_term = taxonomy_term_load(40848);

Comment: Hey Thanks for the help, I just cleared the cache and it is working now. :/

Comment: Ha, that will do it.  Be sure to mark the question as answered if the solution worked.